# Recover Google Developer Account from Project Id

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I have an app which is using a Google Developer Project but I am not able to identify the Google Account that was used for creating the Prject in Google Developer console.

Is there a way we can identify the Google Account used for a Project Id or API Key?

Comment: You'd probably have to contact some Google Support channel. Is remaking the project not an option?

Comment: @Andy If I create new Project I loose all old data.